# Windows Media Services Web Streaming

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, flash, jwplayer, windows-media-center

Which web player I can use to get live stream from Windows Media Services? Is there are any crossplatform solutions (Windows, iPad/iPhone)? Should I make live convertation to flv or any other trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using h264/aac video format for targeting iOS systems as explained in this article: [Apple HTTP Live Streaming with IIS Media Services](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/854/apple-http-live-streaming-with-iis-media-services/) (this is kind of your only choice if you want to support iphone/ipad etc). This format will also be valid for [Windows Phone 7 devices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). 

For the rest of Windows-based systems you could use [Silverlight as streaming client](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/835/live-and-on-demand-video-with-silverlight-and-iis-smooth-streaming/), although you will need to use a different format [based on Windows Media Video](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/05/06/streaming-media-in-silverlight.aspx).